# Jquery and CFML - datepicker inside CFdiv

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I'm going to repeat a question I asked earlier but I need help using datepicker.  I don't see how to use the same solution I got for an .on('click') problem. I can see how datepicker might be an on.click event. The solution was to put the CFdiv inside a div and listen for onclick on an element inside that element.  The input for the datepicker functions below is;

```
<cfinput type="text" class="datestuff" name="IndepthWRec" id="IndepthWRec" value="#CandidateChecklistInfo.IndepthWRec#" />
```

I have a CF page that has a CFdiv. The Cfdiv is bound to an element on the page. The main page contains the script. None of the script executes on elements in the CFdiv. There seems to be a problem with the ajax call. When I take that code out, the rest of the code seems to be enabled in Firebug but still will not execute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#candidatesubmit').on('click', function () {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'actEditStatusForm.cfm',
      data: 'form=',
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)(
      // show error 
      alert(errorThrown);),
      success: function (response1, textStatus, jqXHR)(
      alert('success');)
       });
    ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('candidatesGrid', true);
  });
  $(function () {$("#JDOrgChartRESOutlineSentToCand").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});});
  $(function () {$("#IndepthWRec").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});});
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is some kind of conflict between the jQuery library and the ExtJS library used by ColdFusion's AJAX implementation? `<cfdiv>` and other ColdFusion AJAX elements like `<cfinput>` will load a bunch of JS code at the top of the page. We've had issues where this will conflict with jQuery code and tend to stay away from those tags where at all possible. Now that might not be possible for you in this case; perhaps you should look into using another datepicker such as (ugh) `<cfcalendar>` (if your end-users are using Flash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading the form with ajax, you need to initialize the datepicker within the success callback of the ajax after the new html has been inserted. You can't call datepicker prior to the element's existence so delegation methods like `on()` are useless

Comment: The form contains cflayouts for tabs and one has a cfgrid. The Cfdiv is bound to one of those cfgriditems. So, I don't actually have a callback. Not easily accessible anyway.  This is a complicated page and I don't want to re-write much of it just now.

Comment: rules are simple... can't call datepicker until html for it exists

Comment: I found most of the answer [link]http://www.raymondcamden.com/forums/messages.cfm?threadid=D4968C47-F81C-B20A-1A5E85BFF9991B7B[/link]